# How to limit Find All References in Visual Studio to just the variable concerned

Tags: c++, visual-studio

With C++ files, why does the right-click option to 'Find All References' of a variable usage return all spelling usages in the entire project whether related or not.
How can this Find operation be limited to just the actual variable concerned?

Comment: It, um, doesn't. I use this all the time. It finds all references to the selected object in the project, just like it says in the documentation. No one can help you to fix this unusual problem; there is not nearly enough information provided. I would blame your system configuration first.

Comment: The VS version matters a lot.  Works pretty well since VS2013, it is not perfect.  If your code cannot be compiled since you are busy editing it, and thus prevents proper syntactic analysis, then it does have to fall back to the crummy way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for MSVC 2015 Update 2 it does actually find all the references to a variable, including comments and strings.

When you get a list of references you can see different icons for each element denoting different types of references: like comments, strings or variables with the same name. Then you have two options when walking though the list: visit all found locations (F4, Shift+F4) or only **confirmed references** using the black arrow buttons, as shown here:

[image: Find Symbol Results buttons]

I would also recommend to rescan solution if searching doesn't work correctly (Solution Explorer > right click > Rescan Solution).

Comment: Wow, that Answer really helped me a lot. I was thinking the feature is broke but it's actually just very uncomfortable :-) I probably would've never tried using these arrow buttons. Thx finnan

Comment: @tibx, maybe you have to wait some time. In the first 2 lines of the result window it says **100% of items left to process**, then the percentage goes down until the line disappears. For large solutions this might take a while. And clicking the arrow buttons only has an effect when there are confirmed refs found already.

Answer (score -1):

For those that have Visual Assist, *Find References* (Alt+Shift+F) will give you all relevant references to the variable you're looking for.